# Submit form after ajax request complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a signup form which takes username. And I want to validate username via ajax before submitting the form.

**HTML**

```
<form name="su_form" action="/usersignup/" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

**Script**

```
function validateForm() {

var f  = document.forms["su_form"]["username"].value;

//validate username
$.ajax({
url: "/check_username/",
type: 'post',
data: {
  "username": f
},
statusCode: {
  400: function() {
    $('#username').append("Username already exist");
    $('#username').addClass("disblock");
  }
 }
});
}
```

If I put the `return false;` inside `statusCode` function it doesn't affect the enclosing function.

I tried binding it with variable

```
function validateForm() {

var f  = document.forms["su_form"]["username"].value;
var okay = "true";

//validate username
$.ajax({
url: "/check_username/",
type: 'post',
data: {
  "username": f
},
statusCode: {
  400: function() {
    $('#username').append("Username already exist");
    $('#username').addClass("disblock");
    okay = "false";
  }
 }
});
}

return okay;
```

Because ajax is asynchronous request binding it with variable doesn't help. The form submits before the ajax completes.

Comment: This is not a proper practice to validate existing user. You leave a time gap between server responding and the form submitting to break the validation. Instead submit the form anyway and validate data on server side then return error if any to alert the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery Ajax allow you to do a sync request, just add async: false to your Ajax request. More information here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: "async" seems to be deprecated . Is this going to be a problem.

Comment: Oops I miss that. A different approach is preventDefault for all request and if everything is right you do a manual submit. Ex validadeForm(event) { event.preventDefault().... And when you valide your data and everything is OK you call $('#form').submit()

Comment: Tried it. Ajax is inside the validateForm() function, so it goes into infinite loop.